# redirecting some but not all domains to https

Tags: security, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to convince mod-rewrite to redirect http://example.com to https://example.com but not redirect http://subdomain.example.com

I've added the following to the .htaccess file in the sites root,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

and that (as I thought it would) redirects everything, so then I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^http://example(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but that also appears to redirect everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) only matches on the part of the URL after the host and port (in VirtualHost context) or on the relative filesystem path (in Directory/htaccess context); so trying to match a hostname in a RewriteRule will not work.

However `%{HTTP:Host}` will give you the `Host` HTTP header, so that RewriteCond can match against it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} =example.com
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

The drawback is that mod_rewrite will notice that you rewrite conditionally depending on an HTTP header, and will add a `Vary: Host` header. If you don't want that, you may store it to a variable first, and do the RewriteCond on that variable:

```
RewriteRule . - [E=HTTP_HOST_NO_VARY:%{HTTP:Host}]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_HOST_NO_VARY} =example.com
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```